# Slower Execution with Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I may be in a little over my head here, but I am working on a little bioinformatics project in python. I am trying to parallelism a program that analyzes a large dictionary of sets of strings (~2-3GB in RAM). I find that the multiprocessing version is faster when I have smaller dictionaries but is of little benefit and mostly slower with the large ones. My first theory was that running out of memory just slowed everything and the bottleneck was from swapping into virtual memory. However, I ran the program on a cluster with 4*48GB of RAM and the same slowdown occurred. My second theory is that access to certain data was being locked. If one thread is trying to access a reference currently being accessed in another thread, will that thread have to wait? I have tried creating copies of the dictionaries I want to manipulate, but that seems terribly inefficient.  What else could be causing my problems?

My multiprocessing method is below:

```
def worker(seqDict, oQueue):
     #do stuff with the given partial dictionary
     oQueue.put(seqDict)
oQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()
chunksize = int(math.ceil(len(sdict)/4)) # 4 cores
inDict = {}
i=0
dicts = list() 
for key in sdict.keys():
    i+=1
    if len(sdict[key]) > 0:
        inDict[key] = sdict[key]
    if i%chunksize==0 or i==len(sdict.keys()):
        print(str(len(inDict.keys())) + ", size")
        dicts.append(copy(inDict))
        inDict.clear()

for pdict in dicts:
    p =multiprocessing.Process(target = worker,args = (pdict, oQueue)) 
    p.start()
finalDict = {}

for i in range(4):
    finalDict.update(oQueue.get())
return finalDict
```

Comment: Not sure if its applicable to your situation and I don't know a ton about python, but I'm fairly sure using a database like MySQL will be much faster and more efficient for large sets of data like this

Comment: I would venture to say that if your algorithm is not computationally intensive it could be a memory bottle neck. I run into this all the time reading data files off of a hard drive.

Comment: Did creating copies of the dictionaries speed it up?

Comment: My knowledge of python multiprocess is admittedly limited, but if my memory serves, items passed when a process is spawned are pickled and unpickled completely in the act of creating the process.  Have you considered trying to pass only indices for each slice of the original dict to the subprocesses, then piping the source dict to them?  I think using a pipe causes the processes to share memory instead of using the pickle>unpickle duplication of the entire piece of data, so that might help performance with large source dicts.

Comment: @martineau creating copies did speed up the the cpu time a good deal, the real time was just about the same.

Comment: @sr2222 Thanks, this makes sense. I will try to implement something like this. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Looking further at the multiprocess documentation, it looks like you want `multiprocess.Manager`, or, if you can simplify your dataset, `multiprocess.Array` or `multiprocess.Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the data from the "large dictionary of sets of strings" could be reformatted into a something that could be stored in a file or string, allowing you to use the `mmap` module to share it among all the processes. Each process might incur some startup overhead if it needs to convert the data back into some other more preferable form, but that could be minimized by passing each process something indicating what subset of the whole dataset in shared memory they should do their work on and only reconstitute the part required by that process.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've looked into a lot of stuff and I realize that the data must be completely parsed into a dictionary first because I have organize it into groups (can't think of another way to do this). I could then rewrite it to a sorted file and open it with mmap - but I am not sure this overhead is worth it. I might have to do this same processing on 10-20GB files instead of the current 500-1000MB files, so then I assume I would have to do this.

Comment: I understand. You could easily turn the dictionary (or subset of it) into a long string, either manually or using `pickle.dumps()` and store that in the `mmap`. Reconstitution should be equally easy. Nothing needs to be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments, and as Kinch said in his answer, everything passed through to a subprocess has to be pickled and unpickled to duplicate it in the local context of the spawned process.  If you use `multiprocess.Manager.dict` for `sDict` (thereby allowing processes to share the same data through a server that proxies the objects created on it) and spawning the processes with slice indices in to that shared `sDict`, that should cut down on the serialize/deserialize sequence involved in spawning the child processes.  You still might hit bottlenecks with that though in the server communication step of working with the shared objects.  If so, you'll have to look at simplifying your data so you can use true shared memory with `multiprocess.Array` or `multiprocess.Value` or look at `multiprocess.sharedctypes` to create custom datastructures to share between your processes.

Comment: Thanks, I realize now I am going to have to simplify my data's structure if I want to efficiently do this.

Comment: You should be able to turn your data into a multidimensional array. Just have to use indices instead of keys...

Comment: I converted everything over to a list containing multiprocessing arrays. I am just not sure this is super efficient still. I am using 2+ GB of RAM and 2+GB of swap for only 6mil lines of data in this implementation, which is about double what I had before - probably because I am still load everything into a dictionary to start as its the simplest way to group the data. I guess I could read and sort in the arrays from the file, but the sorting wouldn't be easy since it based on a file read parallel to the first one. I am probably just going to have to live with excessive memory use here.

Answer (score 0):

Every data which is passed through the queue will be serialized and deserialized using pickle. I would guess this could be a bottleneck if you pass a lot of data round.

You could reduce the amount of data, make use of shared memory, write a multi-threading version in a c extension or try a multithreading version of this with a multithreading safe implemention of python (maybe jython or pypy; I don't know).

Oh and by the way: You are using multiprocessing and not multithreading.